# how to open Delete the ~/.cache folder

Tags: directory

I need to delete VLC cache. I didn't know to do it. So I googled it.
The answer I got was:
Delete the ~/.cache/vlc folder
But I don't know how to open ~/ folders
Could you help me?

Comment: `~` is a shortcut for your `home` directory with default location `/home/username`. For your specific problem, you can follow Deyvison Rochas answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open *Nautilus* (Files program)
2. Go to `User` folder.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (With this command show all hide files and folders).
4. Find *.cache* folder and enter.
5. Find *vlc* folder and delete.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer command line

open terminal

> rm -r ~/.cache/vlc

would do the trick